# $\exists\text{ set }X:X=X^X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given sets A and B, define the set $B^A$ to be the set of all functions A $\to$ B.

My question is: Is there a set X such that X = $X^X$?

Has this something to do with the axiom of regularity?

Comment: Hint: look at cardinalities.

Comment: Related question: what is the result set when considering $\varnothing^{\varnothing}$?

Comment: @abiessu $\emptyset^\emptyset = \{\emptyset\}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: ah, missed it by that much...

Comment: To be clear: are you regarding a function $A\to B$ as a subset of $A\times B$?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

1. By a cardinality argument it follows $|X|=1$.
2. Now, can such a $X$ satisfy $X = X^X$?

Comment: Then if $X = \{a\}$, we would need to be able to identify $a$ with the map $f:X \to X$ given by $f(a) = a$, that is (under the usual definitions) the set $\{(a,a)\}$. I would think that regularity forbids $a = \{\{(a,a)\}\}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That's why I asked about Op's def of "function". He says "equals", not "has the same cardinality as", so I'm worried.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: oh, right. I missed that is set equal not cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a function $X\to X$ is really a subset $f\subseteq X\times X$ satisfying the requirement $$\forall a\in X.\ \exists! b\in X.\ (a, b)\in X.$$ Also, note that a pair $(a, b)$ is defined as the set $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$.

Now, suppose there is an $X$ with $X=X^X$. Since $\emptyset$ is obviously not the same as the set $\emptyset^{\emptyset}=\{\mathrm{id}_\emptyset\}$ and for $X$ with $|X| \geq 2$ we have $|X^X| \geq |2^X|> |X|$ and therefore $X\not = X^X$, we can infer that $|X|=1$. Let $X=\{\bullet\}$. This unique element $\bullet\in X$ has to be equal to the function $\mathrm{id}_X$ because we supposed $X$ to be the same as $X^X = \{\mathrm{id}_X\}$. According to our definitions $$\mathrm{id}_X=\{(\bullet, \bullet)\}=\{\{\{\bullet\}, \{\bullet, \bullet\}\}\}=\{\{\{\bullet\}\}\}.$$ But we have already said that $\mathrm{id}_X=\bullet$. Hence $\bullet=\{\{\{\bullet\}\}\}$ which is forbidden by [the axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).